# Gatsby Mdx frontmatter is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, mdxjs

I have a mdx gatsby page with frontmatter defined.

```
---
title: About Me
path: /about
description: Some information about me.
---

# About Me
[Twitter](https://twitter.com/RainFire336)
```

I have configured a default layout in the `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
  options: {
    defaultLayouts: {
      default: require.resolve("./src/components/page-layout.tsx")
    },
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
      'gatsby-remark-images',
      {
        resolve: 'gatsby-remark-prismjs',
        options: {
          showLineNumbers: true,
          prompt: {
            user: 'rain',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

The layout tries to access the frontmatter using it's props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from './layout';
import { Card } from './card';
import { Metadata } from './metadata';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  uri: string;
  pageContext: { frontmatter: any };
}

export default function (p: Props) {
  const { children, uri, pageContext } = p;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Metadata {...pageContext.frontmatter} url={uri} />
      <Card style={{ width: '50%' }}>{children}</Card>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The problem is that frontmatter is always an empty object:
[image: Debugger with empty frontmatter object]
So to form a question. How do I get access to my frontmatter?

Comment: I have no idea why, but It randomly started working.

Comment: Facing the same issue. None of the answers worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same issue. Re-running `gatsby develop` didn't work for me.

**What worked:**

Any time I added a new key/value in the front-matter, I needed to delete the `.cache` folder at the root of my Gatsby application before re-running `gatsby develop`. Then I was able to access the correct front matter through `pageContext.frontmatter` in my Layout.

It's also worth noting that frontmatter should go before any imports in your MDX files. Like so:

```js
---
foo: 'bar'
---

import './something.js'

# My great MDX
```

**TLDR:**

Delete `.cache` folder in Gatsby project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue.  I had to re-run `gatsby develop` in order for the frontmatter to show up in my `pageContext`.

I've also found that when I update my frontmatter, it doesn't update automatically and I need to restart the `gatsby develop` command in order for it to show up.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible for an outsider to debug your code without a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The best way to debug GraphQL is to use the GraphiQL interface of your browser.

Paste your graphQL query that populates `pageContext` with data into the query window of your GraphiQL editor `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`.

Does the frontmatter contain data?

- If not, there is something wrong with your GraphQL query or your data cannot be queried.
- If it does, you are most likely making a mistake passing the data around or destructuring it. Use `console.log(pageContext)` to examine the data object.

Comment: There is no query. According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/writing-pages/), `props.pageContext.frontmatter` should be automatically populated.